# I call sapi in a thread, get an error code : OLE error 80045006

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sapi

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'OLE error 80045006'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

i have called CoInitialize. My code is :

```
hr := CoInitialize(nil);

SpVoice := TSpVoice.Create(Application);
SpVoice.Connect;
SpVoice.Speak('Test text');

CoUninitialize;
```

and the error only happened when i select the neospeech voice.

Comment: Error 0x80046005 is SPERR_DEVICE_BUSY: Hardware device is in use by another thread or process. MSDN Says: in many older systems, audio output devices can be opened only by a single process. In versions of Windows previous to Windows XP, only a single process can open an audio input device. Therefore, SPERR_DEVICE_BUSY will return if an attempt is made to open a device that is being used by a different process or thread. In Windows XP (and higher), multiple processes can open the same audio device

Comment: @Remko: That could be a full-fledged answer. Would get my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 0x80045006 is SPERR_DEVICE_BUSY: Hardware device is in use by another thread or process. MSDN Says: in many older systems, audio output devices can be opened only by a single process. In versions of Windows previous to Windows XP, only a single process can open an audio input device. Therefore, SPERR_DEVICE_BUSY will return if an attempt is made to open a device that is being used by a different process or thread. In Windows XP (and higher), multiple processes can open the same audio device

Comment: On Windows XP, I still 80045006 when two processes try to use SAPI at the same time.